# Compiling A Typescript Create React App to Import in another React App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I have a Create React App written in Typescript, I will call it MyApp. I want to run this App inside an already existing React App, I will call it ExistingApp.

I would like to use it as follows:

```
import App from "node_modules/@MyApp/src"

function ExistingApp() {
   return (
     <div className="App">
       <App />
     </div>
   );
}

export default ExistingApp;
```

I would like to do this compilation/Transpiling using Webpack. I would like the folder structure to be maintained without bundling everything into a single JS file.
I have managed to achieve the desire outcome with

```
tsc --module commonjs --outDir dist
```

However my .scss files are not being copied to the dist folder. the dist folder only contains the transpilled js files.

Comment: tsc is a Typescript compiler not an asset bundler like Webpack. If you just want to compile scss to css (I guess?) use an scss compiler. Or... use Webpack for every thing.

Comment: Okay, i guess I just want to compile everything with webpack without bundling. How then would I setup my webpack to chieve that?

Comment: The question is: why are you doing that? Having everything in single js files make no sense from an "application point of view".

Answer (score 0):

The below solution is to get webpack to use Sass, with bundling. If you do not want bundling, I wouldn't use webpack at all.

## In production, try:

1. Install these packages with the following command

```bash
npm i --save-dev sass-loader node-sass mini-css-extract-plugin css-loader style-loader
```

2. Add the following code snippet to your webpack config in the rules array (make sure to import MiniCssExtractPlugin in the config file)

```js
{
     test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
     use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

### Import MiniCssExtractPlugin (put this at the top of the config):

```js
import * as MiniCssExtractPlugin from "mini-css-extract-plugin"
```

OR

```js
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin")
```

## In development, you can just do this

1. Same thing as step one in example 1
2. Use this code snippet instead, in the same place as example 1 (no need to import MiniCssExtractPlugin)

```js
{
    test: /\.(s(a|c)ss)$/,
    use: ['style-loader','css-loader', 'sass-loader']
}
```

[Source](https://dev.to/deepanjangh/setting-up-css-and-sass-with-webpack-3cg)